# Rails 4 & mail-2.5.4 - NoMethodError: undefined method `ascii_only?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, actionmailer

This error occurs on production server randomly not for every user. we are using sidekiq for delayed jobs and mandrill for emails. Please find the error backtrace form Airbrake.

My ActionMailer Method is:

```
def auto_reply(email, subject, message)
    mail(to: email, body: message, subject: subject)
end 

/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/common/parameter_hash.rb:44 in block in encoded
/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/common/parameter_hash.rb:43 in map
/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/common/parameter_hash.rb:43 in encoded
/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/content_type_field.rb:113 in encoded
/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/field.rb:167 in method_missing
/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/header.rb:206 in block in encoded
/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/header.rb:205 in each
/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/header.rb:205 in encoded
/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:1801 in encoded
/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/body.rb:153 in block in encoded
/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/parts_list.rb:11 in block in collect
/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/parts_list.rb:11 in each
/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/parts_list.rb:11 in collect
/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/body.rb:153 in encoded
/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:1803 in encoded
/gems/actionmailer-4.0.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:475 in set_payload_for_mail
/gems/actionmailer-4.0.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:455 in block in deliver_mail
/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159 in block in instrument
/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20 in instrument
/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159 in instrument
/gems/actionmailer-4.0.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:454 in deliver_mail
/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:232 in deliver
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.4/lib/sidekiq/extensions/action_mailer.rb:20 in perform
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.4/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:52 in block (2 levels) in process
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.4/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:122 in call
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.4/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:122 in block in invoke
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.4/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:6 in call
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.4/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:124 in block in invoke
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.4/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:74 in call
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.4/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:124 in block in invoke
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.4/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11 in block in call
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.4/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:22 in with_context
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.4/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:7 in call
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.4/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:124 in block in invoke
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.4/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:127 in call
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.4/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:127 in invoke
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.4/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:51 in block in process
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.4/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:94 in stats
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.4/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:50 in process
/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26 in public_send
/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26 in dispatch
/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:122 in dispatch
/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:60 in block in invoke
/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:71 in block in task
/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:357 in block in task
/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:57 in block in initialize
/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:15 in block in create
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you sure your 3 variables: email, subject and message are not `nil?`

Comment: Thanks @duques_l for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your three variables  : `email`, `subject`, or `message` are `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem - using Rails 4.1 no matter what I did when I tried to send out an email I always got the dreaded

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `ascii_only?' for nil:NilClass):
```

For me the problem was related to my mailer settings - one of the components, in this case the SMTP Server Name, was not set up correctly.

I use a local file for semi-secret settings, so my configuration looked like this:

```
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :authentication => :plain,
  :address => SECRET['SMTP_HOST'],
  :port => SECRET['SMTP_PORT'],
  :domain => SECRET['SMTP_DOMAIN'],
  :user_name => SECRET['SMTP_USER'],
  :password => SECRET['SMTP_PASS']
```

}

The SECRET hash is read in application.rb like this

```
secrets_file = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.secrets/myapp.yml"
SECRET = File.exists?(secrets_file) ? YAML.load_file(secrets_file) : {}
```

And the myapp.yml file then simply contains key-value pairs in YAML format.

The reason I got the ascii_only? nil error was because I was simply missing on of the SMTP settings (in my case the :address) - and that caused the error.